# VSCode Python heap[0] is no longer the min after modifying the heap items

Tags: python, heap, sudoku

In VS Code, I have a Python heap variable, which is a list of three-item tuples, defined as

`heapq.heappush(heap, (len(candidates[(i, j)]), i, j))`

At the beginning of debugging, `heap[0]` is always the tuple with the shortest `len(candidates[i, j])`. However, after a few rounds of modifying items (not the top item) in the heap by doing -

```
heap.remove((length, r, c))
heapq.heappush(heap, (length - 1, r, c))
```

, `heap[0]` no longer point to the minimum item. For example, in the debug console, `heap[0]` may show `(3, 4, 5)`, while there exists another heap item `(1, 6, 7)`. Because `1 < 3`, obviously `(3, 4, 5)` shouldn't be above the other item in the heap.

Answer (score 2):

It does not point to the minimum item anymore, since the data structure you have is no longer a heap, after doing a `remove()`.
Python technically allows you to do `list.remove(x)` for some value `x`, but the whole point of a heap is to *only* let you `(heap)pop` or "remove" the lowest value in the heap.

Doing `heap.remove()` is logically incorrect, and will no longer maintain the heap invariant (thus it will act only as a list). Use `heapq.heappop(heap)` to remove elements from a heap instead.

If you still want to remove specific element from the data structure, and want to have access to the smallest element, you can check out sorted lists in Python [here](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/).

Comment: Thanks! Another solution I'm thinking (without 3rd party lib) is if it's a good idea (e.g. time complexity) to do a `heapify` following each modification

Comment: `heapify` will take `O(N)` time for each time (where `N` is the number of elements in the heap). It might not be the most optimal, but yes, a possible solution.